# Why exponential distribution is used to represent channel gain between two communicating entities?

Tags: information-theory

In many many papers the channel fading is represented by a random variable $h$ whose pdf follows exponential distribution. My question is why this is used? By using this pdf we may have higher received power at the destination than the transmitted power at the source. There must be something very crucial that I am missing. I will be very thankful if somebody can explain it how it works? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This means the channel gain is Rayleigh distributed, which characterizes the multi-path propagation of signals. In other words, $\sqrt{h}$ is Rayleigh distributed, so $h$ is exponentially distributed. Also, in many cases, the exponential distribution gives nice closed-form expression.

I think you are considering the singular path loss model: $\|x\|^{-\alpha}$, where $\|x\|$ is the distance between the source and the destination $\alpha > 0$ is the path loss exponent. So if $\|x\| < 1$, the signal gets amplified. But in practice, this is not the case. The singular path loss model is usually considered due to its tractability and has its drawback. A better path loss model is to consider $\min\lbrace1, \|x\|^{-\alpha} \rbrace$.

Comment: Thanks alot Oscar. I agree with you on the signal being amplified if the distance is shorter than $1$ but my question was that the channel gain follows an exponential distribution. So, no matter how much is the path loss there still will be some probability (do to channel gain for fading following exponential distribution) that the received power is higher than the transmit power. If I was unable to clarify my question then please let me know I will provide some theoretical example of my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. Since fading is random, it is possible that at some instant, the transmitted signal might get amplified if the channel is very good. In Rayleigh fading, it may happen if multi-path signals arrive in phase (very unlikely), the received signal is the sum of multiple copies. The relevant quantities regarding the fading level are [level crossing rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_fading#Level_crossing_rate) and average fade duration.

Comment: If this is correct then this means that in order to have tractability we use a random variable that sometimes violate some other physical conditions (because we agreed that it gets amplified due to the summation of the multipaths but in real situation the power will be distributed among those multipath components and hence even they add perfectly should not exceed the value that was transmitted by the transmitter). Is it right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Path loss model is just a model, which made many simplification. Those simplification introduces many constrain of the model, for example, where it holds.

In a multipath model, each path actual is still summation of many indiscriminable sub-path. If each sub-path have similar power, it is easy to derived Rayleight path model if we assume there are infinite sub-path. The infinite sub-path assumption introduces the contradiction that received power is larger than transmitted power.

In actual case, the sub-path number is a limit number. When the path distance is large enough, we assume number of the sub-path is large enough then Rayleight model still hold approximately.